# BRAND NEW HTC Desire 816 Headphone Jack Issue

Tags: htc-desire, 5.1-lollipop, headphones, headphone-jack, htc-desire-816-dual

So I just got my HTC Desire 816 in the mail today. It's been in my hand for like 5 hours haven't even put it in my pocket. It's been encased in plastic before I was holding it. So it can not be lint. I tried to fish out debris from the jack produced nothing. The only thing I changed was downloading lollipop and I had tried the headphones before I did the download so I'm stumped. It plays music amazingly well just not through my headphones. Any advice would be appreciated.